# Looking for example code integrating Qt4 and v4l2 library

Tags: c++, linux, qt, video, v4l2

As topic , i tried source code from official website ( c language based ) , but not so complete , i'd like to see some examples which can dump an image and transfer to a Qt class , QImage or so.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, I would have a look at [kopete](http://kopete.kde.org/). This is a multiprotocol messaging client designed for kde --which libs relies on Qt--. I know it can use v4l2. Hope that helps.

**EDIT**: even better actually is [kapture](http://kapture.berlios.de/)

**EDIT 2**: or maybe this one [v4l2ucp](http://qt-apps.org/content/show.php/v4l2ucp?content=110600)?

Comment: i firstly checked the latter two as the former requires kdelibs , but they both require a header which i don't own on my system:  linux/videodev.h: No such file or directory , i'm on kernel 2.6.38

Comment: @EDIT 2: Strangely enough, the name v4l2ucp reminded me of 2 Girls 1 Cup. Don't ask me why, I guess reddit spoiled me.